# Mining Pool code changes for supporting Bitcoin Cash

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-cash

Since its a bit difficult to to find developer related information for Bitcoin Cash I'm asking here. What changes would be required from a [mining-pool developer's point of view](https://github.com/coinfoundry/mining-core/tree/master/src/MiningCore/Blockchain/Bitcoin) to also support Bitcoin-Cash?

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially work out of the box I believe.

You don't need to worry about replay prevention, or any of that when dealing with outputs generated by mining a block. These are new outputs and they aren't (under normal circumstances) available in the Bitcoin blockchain. 
The BCC client might even provide this protection by default, I don't know. But once you do a payout to a miner, they will certainly add replay prevention if they spend their BCC by default.

https://github.com/coinfoundry/mining-core/blob/master/src/MiningCore/config.json#L218

I suggest you modify the existing BTC tag (instead of adding a new coin BCC), 
https://github.com/coinfoundry/mining-core/blob/master/src/MiningCore/config.json#L218

Change those lines to work with the Bitcoin Cash daemon, instead of connecting to the Bitcoin Core client. Also make sure to modify the pool address to yours.

But I want to run both bitcoin and bitcoin cash - how do I do that?
I'm not going to do the work for you, there are multiple changes required and nobody here will be able to answer you to the full extent. I suggest you edit the BTC tag just because it great simplifies the amount of explanation I have to do and allows you to test if that works before even thinking about an engineered approach. People here generally don't answer software engineering questions, let alone those that involve BCC.

Comment: I wasn't aware that engineering question were OT here and I didn't expect anyone doing my homework either. It's just not that easy to come up with answers without resorting to reading much of the daemon's code. By the way can you clarify why you've linked to the Pool Engine's example config? I sure know how to configure the pool since I developed it.

Comment: I believe the Bitcoin Cash daemon operates over a different port to prevent overlap with Bitcoin Core? I'm not really aware of the exact internals of BCC, except for the replay protection (because that inflicts with Bitcoin Core). I assumed the worst as the question seemed like a "halp me make thiz other person software wurk for bcc plz", my apologies. Hooking it up to the Bitcoin Cash daemon should be all that's needed to get this baby to purr I believe.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold 

https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L155

The ports are the same by default, you'll want a custom configuration if you're running both bitcoind and bitcoind-abc on the same machine. Also they have all the same base58 prefixes (for addresses, xpub keys, etc). It's basically all the same values that make up bitcoin (no changes to the chain params like with an altcoin).

Comment: Yeah I'm fully aware of the differences in port allocation. But this is a devops issue that is already solved. I need to make sure that share processing and payouts work as expected for the miners.

Comment: I updated my comment with a bit more information, let us know if it works. You've got me curious.

Comment: Will do. Too bad that none of the BCC developers are active here.